# Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) TestResults - Open attachment in browser

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, msbuild, azure-devops, mstest

We're using `MSTest` with Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) builds to run our Selenium Tests and, for the failed ones, I'm taking a screenshot in the `TestCleanup` that added to the Test Results by using `TestContext`.

Now, when I'm checking the test results for the failed tests, and want to open the attachment (a `.png` image), Team Services is always prompting for download instead of just displaying it in the browser, which could really become a pain when you have a new build of your app and a lot stuff was changed causing multiple tests to fail.

Is there any possibility to force Team Services or the browser to open the images in the browser?
I'm open to anything from changing the type of attachment, potential "hacks" that could determine Team Services to display the image in browser, browser extensions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any option to configure this at VSTS/VSO side for now, I have help you submit a feature request on VSTS User Voice, refer to this link for details: [Open attachments of test result from web portal in browser](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15449214-open-attachments-of-test-result-from-web-portal-in).

However, if you are using Firefox, I know there is an [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/) add-on which allow you to open the document from browser directly.